# Regexp with spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have regexp pattern like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s(INV|FINAL)\s([0,1]?\d{1}\s(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\s(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3})))(\s{1})\d+$
```

This pattern should validate if the document name is correct
Document name like this should match this pattern:

```
1207181 FINAL 12 13 12 1533
```

At the beginning - just numbers, it's like id.

Next one space.

Next INV or FINAL word.

Next date in format dd mm yy.

Next some digits.

Can anybody help me to resolve this?

Comment: There are many variants of regexp, which application or language are you using them in?

Comment: The problem is that this

Comment: regexp doesn't work correctly

Comment: Can anybody help me to write regexp according to my conditions?

Comment: @Alex: If you want help, then state what exactly the problem is. If you want someone to write the regex for you, this is not the correct website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're searching for:

```
^(\d+)\s(INV|FINAL)\s(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\s(\d{2})\s(\d+)$
```

Explanation:

```
^                      start at the beginning of the string
(\d+)                  capture any digit
\s                     one whitespace
(INV|FINAL)            captrue INV or FINAL
0[1-9]                 a 0 and a digit from 1 to 9
[12]\d                 a 1 or a 2 and a digit
3[01]                  a 3 and a 0 or a 1
(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[01]) capture a digit from 01 to 31
(0[1-9]|1[0-2])        capture a 0 and a digit from 1 to 9 or a 1 and a digit from 0 to 2 | so capture a digit from 01 to 12
(\d{2})                capture two digits
$                      stop at the end of the string
```

It won't match `1207181 FINAL 12 13 12 1533` because of the `13`.